# Where to call Control.Invoke/BeginInvoke in multi-thread operation?

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, invoke

I was writing a sample using delegates and updating `UI` from other `threads,` and came across this question.
 Here's my sample code;

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private decimal _sum;
    private delegate void SetSum();
    private readonly SetSum _setSum;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _setSum = () =>
        {
            txtSum.Text = _sum.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        };
    }
    private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Thread(Method).Start();
    }
    private void Method()
    {
        for (decimal i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            _sum += i;
        }
        //txtSum.BeginInvoke(_setSum);
        this.BeginInvoke(_setSum);
    }
}
```

What is the difference if I call the BeginInvoke method on `this` and `txtSum`? Both are controls from the UI thread, and both give no exception invoking my delegate and to their job great, so how to decide what control to pick for calling the delegate?

Comment: If both belong to same UI thread there is no difference which one to use (up to you, e.g. you can invoke in the form member by using form instance or you can do that in custom control, where you don't required to get `Form` instance, it will be enough to use control instance itself). What it does is to simply send message to that UI window message processing (google for message pump).

Comment: The same question was asked here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149789/control-invoke-and-parent-control

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

The method `Control.BeginInvoke()` is executed on a thread that the control's underlying handle was created on... In your case it should make no difference.

According to MSDN :

> The delegate is called asynchronously, and this method returns
>   immediately. You can call this method from any thread, even the thread
>   that owns the control's handle. If the control's handle does not exist
>   yet, this method searches up the control's parent chain until it finds
>   a control or form that does have a window handle. If no appropriate
>   handle can be found, BeginInvoke will throw an exception.
>
> Most methods on a control can only be called from the thread where the
>   control was created. In addition to the InvokeRequired property, there
>   are four methods on a control that are thread safe: Invoke,
>   BeginInvoke, EndInvoke, and CreateGraphics if the handle for the
>   control has already been created

More info from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Think of this scenario:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Control c;

    public Form1()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { c = new Control(); });          
    }
}
```

If you use `this.BeginInvoke(someMethod)` it's possible that it throws an exception when you try to invoke method of a Control from a different thread than the one where it was created (from UI thread in our case). So that's when it might be better use `c.BeginInvoke(someMethod)`...

Comment: Yeah so could you please give an example where it does make difference, because I want to get the idea.

Comment: Try to think conceptually using Fabjans answer. Every control has a handle which must be created on a specific thread, e.g. the UI thread. BeginInvoke is then executed on the thread's dispatcher. Imagine a Webrequest which runs on its own thread. On request success you set the response text as the text on the textbox. Calling this.BeginInvoke in the request handler would invoke the delegate on the webrequest thread. TxtBox.BeginInvoke on the UiThread.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a control to Begin/Invoke() to because Winforms needs to figure out which specific thread needs to execute the delegate target.  It will be the thread that created the Handle property.  Underlying winapi call is [GetWindowThreadProcessId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Otherwise the reason it will spit bullets when you call Begin/Invoke() to early or too late.

The choice is superseded by another rock-hard rule, the child controls of a toplevel window *must* be created on the same thread as the window.  Kaboom if it wasn't.

So it just doesn't matter, you have a hard guarantee that the TextBox and the Form both will marshal to the exact same thread.

But it is better not to have to make the choice at all.  You are always fighting a threading race bug when you do, nothing pretty ever happens when the thread survives a bit longer than the window.  Pretty inevitable because the lifetime of the window and its controls is not directly under your control.  It is the user that decides when they get disposed.  But it is you that controls the thread.  The BackgroundWorker and Task classes make it a lot easier to reason about this.